# Размещение текста в объекте

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

Возможно глупый вопрос.
Нужна помощь, я еще учусь, навыков не так много, но хочется завершить начатую работу, я многое сделала, но осталось самое сложное для меня.

Пример того, как должен выглядеть конечный результат:
[image: Пример того, как должен выглядеть конечный результат:]

В рамке сумма должна быть справой стороны, с левой — все остальное.
Как только добавила линию, которая на скриншоте находиться над Total - все сразу слетело. Я много что перепробовала, но все не подходит.

Мой код сейчас выглядит так:

```html
<div style="box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 32px;
  gap: 24px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #D7D6DC;
  border-radius: 12px;
  align-self: stretch;">
  <th:block th:each="companyName : ${companyName}">
    <p style="line-height: 140%;
      color: #333333;
      font-size: 14px;
      flex: none;
      display: table;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      text-align: left;
      height: 100%;
      width: 80%;" th:text="${companyName}">пример название
    </p>
  </th:block>
  <th:block th:each="amount : ${amount}">
    <p style="line-height: 140%;
      color: #333333;
      font-size: 14px;
      flex: none;
      display: table;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      text-align: right;
      height: 100%;
      width: 10%;" th:text="${amount}"> сумма
    </p>
  </th:block>
  <div style="width: 408px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #D7D6DC;
    flex: none;
    align-self: stretch;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Как мне сделать чтобы в рамке все текста отображались на своем месте (не зависимо от количества строк) и "разделяющая" полоса была на своем месте?

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю что-то типо этого вам нужно было?
Не нужно полоску создавать, как отдельный объект, просто сумме задаёте border-top

```html
<div style="
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 30px auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 32px;
  gap: 24px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #D7D6DC;
  border-radius: 12px;
  flex-direction: column;
  ">
    <th:block th:each="companyName : ${companyName}"
    style="
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    "
    >
        <p style="line-height: 140%;
      color: #333333;
      font-size: 14px;
      flex: none;
      display: table;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      text-align: left;
      height: 100%;
      width: 80%;" th:text="${companyName}">пример название продукта
        </p>
        <p>24$</p>
    </th:block>
    <th:block th:each="companyName : ${companyName}"
        style="
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        "
    >
        <p style="line-height: 140%;
      color: #333333;
      font-size: 14px;
      flex: none;
      display: table;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      text-align: left;
      height: 100%;
      width: 80%;" th:text="${companyName}">пример название продукта
        </p>
        <p>24$</p>
    </th:block>
    <th:block th:each="amount : ${amount}"
        style="
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            border-top: 1px solid #D7D6DC;
        "
    >
        <p style="line-height: 140%;
      color: #333333;
      font-size: 14px;
      flex: none;
      display: table;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      height: 100%;
      width: 10%;" th:text="${amount}"> сумма
        </p>
        <p>48$</p>
    </th:block>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! очень помогло!